# Android : Dynamic fill contents of view

Tags: android, android-activity

Suppose I have an Android app like image below.

At the *MainActivity* (left) I have a ListView with 50 items for example. 
Each item has a detail page (right) and the detail page has the same format for all items.

[image: my app schema]

How can I fill the detail layout with related contents to *item i* every time I‌ selected one item ?

and What is the best solution (data structure) to save my contents ?

Answer (score 0):

I think yes, you can use FrameLayout and two layouts in it. one is visible, and other is not. But it is better way to use **[Android Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)**.
If use FrameLayout or Linear:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible"></LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/detailed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"></RelativeLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: you can use any layout instead of FrameLayout.

Comment: My question was edited. I want to use 1 layout except the main layout. Main question is what can I have many different contents with same layout? (here i mean detail layout)